# How can I update kuberenet pod based on configuration change?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a configuration file like below. I deploy it to EKS cluster successfully. However, when I change the `nginx-conf` ConfigMap and run `kubectl apply` command, it doesn't seem to update the `nginx.config` in the pod. I tried to login to the pod and look at the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.config` but its content is still the old one.

I have tried to run `kubectl rollout status deployment sidecar-app` but it doesn't help.

And it shows the updated config map when I run `kubectl describe configmap nginx-conf`.

It seems the container doesn't take the config map change. How can I apply the changes without deleting the pod?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-conf
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    user nginx;
    worker_processes  1;
    events {
      worker_connections  10240;
    }
    http {
      server {
          listen       8080;
          server_name  localhost;
          location / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:9200/;
          }
          location /health {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health;
          }
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sidecar-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: sidecar-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: sidecar-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:latest
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-conf
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
              subPath: nginx.conf
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-conf
          configMap:
            name: nginx-conf
            items:
              - key: nginx.conf
                path: nginx.conf

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sidecar-entrypoint
spec:
  selector:
    name: sidecar-app
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sidecar-ingress-1
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: sidecar-ingress
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /health
    # alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: '8080'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: sidecar-entrypoint
              servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: you can do the rollingupdate by updating the metadata of pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes treats POD and Configmap as a different/separate object and pods don't automatically restart on specific Configmap version.

There are few alternatives to achieve this.

1 ) Reloader: `https://github.com/stakater/Reloader`

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 annotations:
   reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
spec:
 template: metadata:
```

2. configHash annotation.
   `https://blog.questionable.services/article/kubernetes-deployments-configmap-change/`
3. Use wave.
   `https://github.com/wave-k8s/wave`
4. You can use `kubectl rollout restart deploy/sidecar-app` but this will restart the pods with zero downtime. Rolling updates allow Deployments' update to take place with zero downtime by incrementally updating Pods instances with new ones.

Comment: I think this command `kubectl rollout restart deploy/sidecar-app` is the easiest way for me. But what does `deploy` mean? Is it `deployment`?

Comment: Yes, a short form of deployment.